# TensorFlow Transfer Learning with Increasing Labels

Tags: tensorflow

For example if I've trained on CIFAR-10 (10 classes) and I would like to transfer to train on MNIST-10 (10 classes) while retaining the ability for inference on the labels of CIFAR-10 and MNIST-10, how would one go about to continually increase the number of labels?

Do we simply concatenate the labels from CIFAR-10 and MNIST-10 and change the readout layer to 20 classes?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply concatenate the classes and fill zeros in the output for each other's classes.